# Ckeditor in the style of a document editor

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x, django-ckeditor

I'm using ckeditor on my system to edit some documents. I don't understand how to configure it to be like a document editor. Thus:

[image]

The [documentation](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_example_setups.html#document-editor) doesn't make it very clear.

The documentation talks about styling it to look like a sheet of paper with [css styles](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/features/styles.html), but it doesn't show an example of what this layout would look like.